# Retrieve partially downloaded byte chunks from DownloadDataAsync

Tags: c#, download

I need to download a binary file and access the raw data as it arrives.

```
    private void Downloadfile(string url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += DownloadDataCompleted;
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressCallback;
        client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(url));
    }

    public void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        long bytes = e.BytesReceived;
        long total = e.TotalBytesToReceive;
        int progress = e.ProgressPercentage;
        string userstate = (string)e.UserState;
        byte[] received = ?
    }
```

Alternatively, writing to a stream would also be helpful. I don't mind using another download method either, the primary goal is to read a download on the fly.

Comment: You can try the `WebClient.OpenRead` if you want. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/781fwaz8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `WebClient.OpenRead` as suggested by Søren Lorentzen

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    using (var stream = client.OpenRead(address))       
    {
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];

        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(readBuffer, totalBytesRead, readBuffer.Length - totalBytesRead)) > 0)
        {
            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

            if (totalBytesRead == readBuffer.Length)
            {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();
                if (nextByte != -1)
                {
                    byte[] temp = new byte[readBuffer.Length];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, temp, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                    Buffer.SetByte(temp, totalBytesRead, (byte)nextByte);
                    readBuffer = temp;
                    totalBytesRead++;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: Hold on, why create the temp array at size readBuffer.Length * 2 ?

Comment: No need for that, just removed it. I didn't clean up the code correctly from my custom implementation.